# How to use Period.parse()?

Tags: java, android, period, periodformatter

Period.parse() requires API level 26. Is there any workaround to use it with minimum API level 17.

I am using

```
Period snoozeTime = Period.parse(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("snoozeTime")));
```

Comment: No, because `Period` itself is new to API Level 26. You would need to look into a third-party date/time library.

Comment: For Java 6 & Java 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For older Android, the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: May I ask you what kind of input needs to be parsed? Examples? I could enhance my answer if I knew what format exactly you want to parse.

Comment: Thank you, I am using joda-time library.

Comment: @BasilBourque, shouldn't it be the ThreeTenABP for all android versions due to criminal ineficiencies in resource and service loading mechanisms on Android?

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using [ThreetenABP](https://github.com/jakewharton/threetenabp) (a wrapper around the backport of JSR-310) might be to get the same feeling as if you use `java.time.Period`, but you have to change the import statement, namely `org.threeten.bp.Period`.

Duration parsers for Android are also available in [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) (called `PeriodFormatter`) or in my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) (for example [pattern-based](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.Formatter.html) or as ISO-8601-parsing-methods in class [Duration](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html#parsePeriod-java.lang.String-)).

Note that the external APIs of Joda-Time and Time4J/A are superior to the parsing capabilities of JSR-310-class `java.time.Period`. Latter one can only understand some few ISO-8601-standard formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just use  Java 8+ API desugaring support. Take a look:  https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

It's meant to provide the new java 8 features on Android with older apis

It's even recommended by ThreetenABP in its github page